# How to add a class to body element if it's a frontpage in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

last days I have been writing my own WordPress theme, but I run into another problem. These times I have no clue, how to make it possible.

I would like to add a class to every frontpage on my website. So if a single page becomes a frontpage, it will get another class to body tag like "home".

Almost every premium theme gots this funcion, but I just cant find the solution.

Does anybody have any idea?

Thank you! Stepan

Answer (score 5):

You can add the class in `body` tag using `body_class` filter as shown below:

```
function home_body_class($classes) {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        $classes[] = 'home';
    }

    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'home_body_class' );
```

You can manipulate the condition for the static `homepage`, `blog` page and so on.

Comment: That's it what I was looking for. Thanks!